# Optimal ordering policy in inventory model

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

Determine the optimal ordering policy in the case of a single period inventory model with no setup cost instantaneous stock replenishment and amount demanded is a continuous random variable.

In this question I am confused about whether the question is asking about deterministic model or stochastic models , because generally if demand is variable as given in the question then it must be stochastic, but I am not able to understand the significance of information regarding the setup cost and 'single period inventory model'.

Comment: I think the model should be deterministic. And at a single period inventory you order once only and not multiply times.  Hint: If the length of the period is $T^*$ and the order quantity is $Q^*$ than the slope of the quantity is consstantly $-\frac{Q^*}{T^*}$. So the function for the inventory quantity is $Q(t)=-\frac{Q^*}{T^*}\cdot t+Q^*$

Comment: @callculus hey could you please elaborate,  I am having a lot of problems in inventory models